# How to split and execute JDBC insert sql queries per each splitted values in JMeter

Tags: mysql, jmeter

I have a requirement of reading a .csv file and and split one particular parameter value and execute database calls for each spitted strings. For example I have entries in the .csv file as follows.

```
{user}, {email}, {keys} ,{age}
---------------------------------
user1, user1@ws.com, user1-key1:user1-key2:user1-key3, 28
user2, user2@ws.com, user2-key1, 29
user3, user3@ws.com, user3-key1:user3-key2:user3-key3:user4-key4, 50
```

My requirement here is to split the value comes with {key} parameter at the delimiter of ':' and execute database inserts per each key value. Basically I need following database inserts after executing the jmeter script.

```
Username  |  email      | key           | Age
------------------------------------------------
user1     |user1@ws.com |  user1-key1   | 28 
user1     |user1@ws.com |  user1-key2   | 28 
user1     |user1@ws.com |  user1-key3   | 28 
user2     |user2@ws.com |  user2-key1   | 28 
..............
user3     |user3@ws.com |  user3-key1   | 50
```

The number of keys coming with {key} parameter value can be changed from 1 to any number. How should we write Jmeter script to achieve above target. We tried to use http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__split  Jmeter Split function but we failed in applying split correctly. Can somebody please help to figure out a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by myself. Below are the steps I followed.

1. Adding a BeanShell sampler to extract the key string, split it and set as a variable set. (var_{counterNo})
2. Adding ForEach Controller to read variables with prefix of 'var' and set that value as an output variable. Then that output variable value has been used for JDBC insert in the JDBC sampler added under ForEach Controller..